# AngularJS: Mock object injected to controller trough router's resolve

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, karma-runner

I'm trying to test a controller that receives an object trough router's resolve:

`app.js`:

```
...
.when('/confirm', {
  templateUrl: 'views/confirm.html',
  controller: 'ConfirmCtrl',
  resolve: {
    order: function(Order) {
      return Order.current;
    }
  }
})
...
```

`ConfirmCtrl.js`:

```
angular.module('angularGeolocationApp').controller('ConfirmCtrl',
function($scope, order, ...) {

  $scope.order = order

  ...

});
```

My Test looks like this:

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: ConfirmCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('angularGeolocationApp'));

  var ConfirmCtrl,
    scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ConfirmCtrl = $controller('ConfirmCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('should get an order object', function () {
    expect(_.isObject(scope.order)).toBeTruthy();
  });

  ...
});
```

However first expectation fails:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.2 (Mac OS X) Controller: ConfirmCtrl should get an order object FAILED
    TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.
        at workFn (/Users/jviotti/Projects/Temporal/angular/angular-geolocation/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2107)
    Expected false to be truthy.
```

My assumption is that as I'm unit testing the isolated controller, the router doesn't have a change to run the resolve function and assign the correct value.

Is there a way to mock that `order` dependency?

I know I can get rid of the resolve stuff and inject `Order` and instantiate `$scope.order` to `Order.current` in the controller itself, but I'd like to keep the `resolve` approach.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just put your own order into the constructor of the ctrl like this.

```
describe('Controller: ConfirmCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('angularGeolocationApp'));

  var ConfirmCtrl,
      scope,
      order


  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    order = {};
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ConfirmCtrl = $controller('ConfirmCtrl', {
      $scope: scope,
      order: order
    });
  }));

  it('should get an order object', function () {
    expect(_.isObject(scope.order)).toBeTruthy();
  });

  ...
});
```

regards

Comment: What if after a few tests, I want to change the value of `order`. How do I do that?